# Why are manifolds defined with open sets?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, surfaces

First a small disclaimer that I have been introduced to manifolds but I am not extremely comfortable with them in the general case yet, however I am taking a course on curves and surfaces (which is almost over) and thus am quite familiar with them (i.e. I know what manifolds are, but I am more used to working with curves and surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^2$).

My question is why is must we restrict ourselves to defining manifolds as homeomorphic to **open** subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. Allowing us to use closed sets would allow us, for example to cover $S^2$ with a single surface patch, as opposed to two, which seems like an attractive property.

I'm going to go on to study more advanced differential geometry very soon and I would love to have a good motivation for this property. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically, to work with calculus you need domains to be open sets. :)

Comment: I think you can find your answer in [Why is a topology made up of 'open' sets?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19152/why-is-a-topology-made-up-of-open-sets/30231#30231).

Comment: @TedShifrin I've overheard this before but I haven't seen something that was a dealbreaker yet, i.e. what's a concrete example of something that just wouldn't work if we weren't working with open sets? I feel like I used the open set properties a million times but everytime I take the fact that things work out for granted!

Comment: @nyquist_plot: A small correction: manifolds are not homeomorphic to open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, but **locally**-homeomorphic.

Comment: @nyquist_plot The "surface patch" you are proposing for $S^2$ is the identity? Because the sphere is not homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. And among many problems, note that if the definition were to consider closed subsets, not even dimension of connected manifolds would be well-defined. Besides, differential topology would stop short without the inverse function theorem, the fact that an atlas provides an **open** cover etc etc etc.

Comment: Possibly a good property of locally homeomorphic to open sets in $\Bbb R^n$ is that manifolds will be locally path-connected, which would be good for doing calculus because we want to study how the value of function changes along a curve (i.e. differentiation). This property cannot be captured by closed sets because there are badly behaving closed sets, e.g. [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Comment: Eventually you will define functions on your manifold to do calculus, and then when you need to check differentiability, you will need open sets, because if you have a function on a closed set, it is differentiable if it extends to a differentiable function on some open set including that closed set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open sets (of fixed dimension) have a single "local model", namely an open ball. For closed sets, by contrast, matters are about as nasty as one can imagine:

- In a Hausdorff space, points are closed; calling a Hausdorff space a "manifold" if for every point $p$, there exists a closed set $V$ containing $p$ and a homeomorphism from $V$ to some closed set in a Cartesian space is no condition at all. (Take $V = \{p\}$.)
- Most closed sets are not the closure of an open set, e.g., non-empty closed sets with empty interior. The preceding point aside, there is no hope of deducing any kind of structure on a space locally modeled on closed sets.

Answer (score 1):

What type of set is a function differentiable on?