# A slight generalization of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Yes, I know that Banach manifolds, Frechet manifolds, orbifolds, and many other possible generalizations exist (but I don't know much about them yet), but can this be one possible generalization of a manifold?

So you know how the neighborhood around every point on a topological manifold is homeomorphic to $R^n$? What if they're homeomorphic to general metric spaces(n-dimensional), instead of euclidean space? Would that be a slight generalization? or would it be equivalent to defining it as being homeomorphic to $R^n$? I'm not sure how to explain it but I think it might be the latter instead of the former.

Comment: What do you mean by the dimension of a metric space?

Comment: @Alessandro wait, the dimension for a metric space isn't defined? can't you define an n-dimensional metric space as a set containing n-tuples with a metric on it?

Comment: $n$-tuples of what? And can the metric be whatever it wants (as long as it's a metric), or does it have limitations?

Comment: @Arthur Well for a start, n-tuples of real numbers I guess, so basically $R^n$ with a general metric d(x, y) instead of a Euclidean metric, and yes there's no limitation on the metric, it can be whatever as long as it's a metric. So would that definition of a manifold(neighborhoods being homeomorphic to that kind of general metric space) be equivalent to the definition which says every neighborhood must be homeomorphic to $R^n$?

Comment: If you allow for any metric, then the only actual distinguishing feature of spaces consisting of $n$-tuples of real numbers is the cardinality. There is a metric on $\Bbb R$ that makes it isometric to standard euclidean $\Bbb R^{11}$. And the same goes for any other $|\Bbb R|$-sized metric space in place of $\Bbb R^{11}$.

Comment: @Arthur But you can also say that there are metrics on R that make it not isometric to the standard euclidean space right?

Comment: Yup. Any metric space with the same cardinality is isometric to some metric on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135516/discussion-between-mastershooter77-and-arthur).

Comment: I really don't like chat discussions, for a number of reasons, all of them different ways of saying I think it's the wrong format. I know the site encourages it, but I don't like it.

Comment: lol that's fine. So if you define a manifold as being locally similar to a metric space instead of a euclidean space, it would technically be a generalization? and not just restating the same definition differently?

Comment: One serious issue is, the standard definition of a _manifold_ has a [single local model space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210495/why-are-manifolds-defined-with-open-sets) at each point. Attempting to generalize to "metric spaces" loses that.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang What exactly is a model space? Why can't we let the neighborhood around every point on the manifold be homeomorphic to an open subset(open ball) on a metric space? (I'm talking about the kind of metric spaces in the above comments)

Comment: Here, a "model space" is a _single topological space_ (an open ball in a Cartesian $n$-space) such that every point of a connected manifold is homeomorphic to the model space. <> If you ask about "$\mathbf{R}^{n}$ with a general metric", it's not true that all balls of the same radius are homeomorphic (to make a comical understatement). Perhaps you're thinking of metrics induced by a vector space norm or some other special family...?